# Tricky delay on mouseover

Tags: jquery, timeout, mouseover

This is what I have currently:

```
$("#cart-summary").mouseenter(function () {
    $('.flycart').delay(500).slideDown('fast');
});
$(".flycart").mouseleave(function () {
    $('.flycart').delay(500).slideUp('fast');
}).find('a.close').click(function(){
   $(this).parents('.flycart').hide();
});
```

**What it does is:**

If mouseover #cart-summary -> open flycart after 500ms

if mouseout .flycart -> close flycart after 500ms

**What I need is:**

If mouseover #cart-summary for ATLEAST 500ms -> open flycart

if mouseout .flycart for ATLEAST 500ms -> close flycart

**Edited to Add:** I also use hoverIntent, if that can be used here?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the setTimeout to check if a flag you set/unset (I'm using a class) is still valid.

```
$("#cart-summary").mouseenter(function () {
    $("#cart-summary").addClass("hasFocus");
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        if ($("#cart-summary").hasClass("hasFocus")) {
            $('.flycart').slideDown('fast');
        }
      }, 500 );
      });

$("#cart-summary").mouseleave(function () {
    $("#cart-summary").removeClass("hasFocus");
});


$(".flycart").mouseenter(function () {
    $("#cart-summary").removeClass("lostFocus");    
});

$(".flycart").mouseleave(function () {
    $("#cart-summary").addClass("lostFocus");
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        if ($("#cart-summary").hasClass("hasFocus")) { 
            $('.flycart').slideUp('fast');
            }).find('a.close').click(function(){
            $(this).parents('.flycart').hide();
        }
    }, 500)
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you might need the [HoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin.

I don't know if it'll help you with the mouseout ATLEAST 500ms though. But maybe there's an option in there for that.

Comment: Found a similar request here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482029/waiting-x-milliseconds-after-an-event-recheck-and-trigger but I want to use hoverIntent if possible.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin as follows:

```
var config = {    
     sensitivity: 3, // number = sensitivity threshold (must be 1 or higher)    
     interval: 500, // number = milliseconds for onMouseOver polling interval    
     timeout: 500, // number = milliseconds delay before onMouseOut    
};

$(".flycart").hoverIntent(function () {
        $('.flycart').slideDown('fast');
}, function() {
        $('.flycart').slideUp('fast');
}).find('a.close').click(function(){
   $(this).parents('.flycart').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
var timeout,
    $flycart = $(".flycart"),
    $summary = $("#cart-summary"),
    delay = 500;

$summary.mouseenter(function () {
    if (timeout) window.clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = window.setTimeout(function(){
        if ( $flycart.is(":visible") ) {
            $flycart.slideDown('fast');
        }
    }, delay);
});
$flycart.mouseleave(function () {
    if (timeout) window.clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = window.setTimeout(function(){
        if ( $flycart.is(":visible") ) {
            $flycart.slideUp('fast');
        }
    }, delay);
})...
```

Answer (score 0):

offer a solution

```
var mouseenterTimerCart;
var mouseleaveTimerCart;

$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        if (mouseleaveTimerCart) clearTimeout(mouseleaveTimerCart);
        mouseenterTimerCart = setTimeout(function() {
            $("#head-cart .cart_items").show()
        }, 500);
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        if (mouseenterTimerCart) clearTimeout(mouseenterTimerCart);
        mouseleaveTimerCart = setTimeout(function() {
            $("#head-cart .cart_items").hide()
        }, 500);
    }
}, "#head-cart .full, #head-cart .cart_items");
```

will work if the basket is updated dynamically

```
$("#head-cart").html(...crat-html-block...)
```