# jQuery mouseover with timing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a way to trigger a mouseover event only after the mouse was hovering for 1 sec on an element?

```
$("img").mouseover(function () {

 $(this).animate( {opacity:1}, 200);

});
```

Comment: You might want to look at http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: Check the following link [Tricky delay on mouseover](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510594/tricky-delay-on-mouseover)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("img").mouseover(function () {
    $(this).delay(1000).animate( {opacity:1}, 200);
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).clearQueue().stop().animate({opacity:0.2},200);
});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pFz9u/3/)

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/tqa2J/1/

```
$("img").on("mouseover mouseout", function() {
    var tid = 0;
    return function(e) {
        var elem = $(this);
        clearTimeout(tid);
        if (e.type == "mouseover") {
            tid = setTimeout(function() {
                elem.stop(true).animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }, 200);
            }, 1000);
        }
        else {
            console.log(elem);
            elem.stop(true).animate({
                opacity: 0.3
            }, 200);
        }

    };
}());​
```

Comment: It should be noted: hoverIntent is ~1.5kb of code (minified) this solution is like 0.01kb as is.

Comment: @rlemon this also has debugging module built-in `console.log(elem);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the hoverIntent() jQuery plugin found here: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Also, make sure you be careful when using these kinds of things as they do not work on mobile browsers or anything using a touch screen.

Comment: Yeah, unless the touch screen app has a built-in mouse pointer or equivalent that can be detected as a hover event.

Answer (score 0):

You should use setTimeOut function.

```
setTimeOut(function(){$("img").mouseover(function () {

        $(this).animate( {opacity:1}, 200);

});
},1000);
```

It takes time in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a timer function (see [1]) that processes your event 1s later. You can store that function in an array or directly to "window", to let it be cancelable if "mouseout" occurs before the timer function triggers.

[1] http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp